# Charts not plotting in tableViewCell

Tags: swift, charts

I am trying to plot a random chart in a tableViewCell in swift 3 using Charts 3.0.2 (an older pod version because I am using Xcode 8.3)

setChart() function is working in a view controller class.

Here is my TableViewCell Code -

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class ChartTVC: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var barChartView: BarChartView!

    var months: [String]!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }

    func setChart() {
        var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
        barChartView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        for i in 100..<105 {
            let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(45))
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }
        let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Visitor count")
        let chartData = BarChartData()
        chartData.addDataSet(chartDataSet)
        chartData.setDrawValues(true)
        chartDataSet.colors = [Colors.amber]

        let xaxis:XAxis = XAxis()

        barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
        barChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
        barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = xaxis.valueFormatter
        barChartView.chartDescription?.enabled = true
        barChartView.legend.enabled = true
        barChartView.rightAxis.enabled = true
        barChartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
        barChartView.leftAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
        barChartView.data = chartData
    }

}
```

And This is how I am calling it from a view controller class

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChartTVC", for: indexPath) as! ChartTVC
    cell.setChart()

    return cell
}
```

I read many tutorial blogs and I couldn't find anything wrong with the code.
I had set a height constraint for bar chart view. Here's the screenshot.

[image]

Chart text is a label.

Comment: please add `Charts` pod command or github url :)

Comment: It's working in a view controller class, just not in a table view cell. And it's not throwing any errors.

Comment: Are you using this ,  https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts , I need this info for testing :)

Comment: Yes but an older version

Comment: i'm using 3.0.2 it's working look screen shot https://ibb.co/gVbVhS 
،You have another problem that you can not know

Comment: @a.masri it should work for me too. I read many blogs and issues in Charts. Code is simple too. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: If you can attach the project, attach it to us to determine what the problem is, but if you can not do this you have to explain more to us so we can help you

Comment: What type of chart are you trying to implement? Linear, cake, bars?

Answer (score 2):

Try to call this after you set chart data:

```
barChartView.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: It didn't worked. I am using virtual box and simulator to test. I don't know if this information is useful.

Comment: your code works on my side but with new charts version.. Are you setting up cell in xib or storyboard ?

Comment: I am setting up in xib

Comment: How are you registering cell ?

Comment: also did you try cell.setNeedsDisplay() after cell.setChart() ?

Answer (score 0):

I used your same code and updated the cocoa Pods to 'Charts', '~> 4.1'

Replaced  chartData.addDataSet(chartDataSet) to chartData.append(chartDataSet)

```
  self.setBarChart()
  self.setNeedsDisplay()
```

For me also Same Result! :-(

Then after setting `constraint-height` for View of BarChartView in `UITableViewCell`.  **Yahoo**! The BarChart Graph shown.
Please don't forget the `constraint`.