# (ios-charts) Failed to show line chart in UICollectionView without using storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, ios-charts

I want to add a line chart in `UICollectionView` cell by using self-created class, `BaseLineChartView`, which inherit from `LineChartView` in iOS charts API. I have to show different kinds of line charts with single line and multiple lines. So this subclass is used for getting data and setting up the `chartView`. 
After I run the app, the cell only show chart with default `noDataText`. The chart doesn't show up and the change I have done in `noDataText` doesn't work either. But the sentence in the last line of `setChart` function was executed and printed in console.

Here is the code of the class:

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class BaseLineChartView: LineChartView {

    let chartView = LineChartView()
    var months = [String]()
    var unitsSold = [Double]()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        populateData()
        lineChartSetup()
        setChart(dataPoints: months, values: unitsSold)
    }

    func populateData(){
        let _months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"]
        let _unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0]
        months = _months
        unitsSold = _unitsSold
    }

    func lineChartSetup() {
        // MARK: General
        chartView.noDataText = "No Data" //Doesn't work..
        chartView.chartDescription?.enabled = true
        chartView.dragEnabled = false
        chartView.setScaleEnabled(false)
        chartView.pinchZoomEnabled = false
        chartView.highlightPerDragEnabled = true
        chartView.backgroundColor = .lightGray

        chartView.dragXEnabled = true
        chartView.dragYEnabled = false

        // MARK: xAxis
        let xAxis = chartView.xAxis
        xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
        xAxis.labelFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 10, weight: .light)
        xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 192/255, blue: 56/255, alpha: 1)
        xAxis.axisLineColor = UIColor.lightGray
        xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true
        xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        xAxis.centerAxisLabelsEnabled = false
        xAxis.granularity = 1
        xAxis.labelRotationAngle = -90.0

        // MARK: leftAxis
        let leftAxis = chartView.leftAxis
        leftAxis.labelPosition = .outsideChart
        leftAxis.labelFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 10, weight: .light)
        leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        leftAxis.granularityEnabled = true
        leftAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 192/255, blue: 56/255, alpha: 1)

        // MARK: rightAxis
        chartView.rightAxis.enabled = false

        // MARK: legend
        chartView.legend.enabled = false

        // MARK: animation
        chartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 1.5)
    }


    func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

        var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

        for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
            let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry.init(x: Double(i), y: values[i])
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }

        let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
        lineChartDataSet.mode = .cubicBezier
        let lineChartData = LineChartData(dataSet: lineChartDataSet)
        chartView.data = lineChartData

        chartView.scaleXEnabled = true
        chartView.scaleYEnabled = false
        chartView.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10.0)
        chartView.xAxis.setLabelCount(11, force: false)

        print("Create Chart Successfully!") //Successfully show in console.
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

And I add this class into collectionView cell like this:

```
class DailyIndexCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let trackingChart: BaseLineChartView = {
        let chartView = BaseLineChartView()
        return chartView
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addSubview(trackingChart)
        trackingChart.notifyDataSetChanged() //Doesn't work
        self.setNeedsDisplay() //Doesn't work
        setConstraints()
    }

    func setConstraints() {
        //Add constraints of trackingChart

    }


}
```

I've tried the solution in this post but didn't work ='(
[Charts not plotting in tableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49779874/charts-not-plotting-in-tableviewcell)

Answer (score 0):

It's look like you have created property `chartView` in `BaseLineChartView` class and set various params for this property but don't use it. So for resolving your problem remove `chartView` property from `BaseLineChartView` and replace all its occurrences to `self` (or just remove). Also pay attantion to lines `let xAxis = chartView.xAxis` and `let leftAxis = chartView.leftAxis` you don't need to use it.

import UIKit
    import Charts

```swift
class BaseLineChartView: LineChartView {

    var months = [String]()
    var unitsSold = [Double]()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        populateData()
        lineChartSetup()
        setChart(dataPoints: months, values: unitsSold)
    }

    func populateData(){
        let _months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"]
        let _unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0]
        months = _months
        unitsSold = _unitsSold
    }

    func lineChartSetup() {
        // MARK: General
        noDataText = "No Data" //Doesn't work..
        chartDescription?.enabled = true
        dragEnabled = false
        setScaleEnabled(false)
        pinchZoomEnabled = false
        highlightPerDragEnabled = true
        backgroundColor = .lightGray

        dragXEnabled = true
        dragYEnabled = false

        // MARK: xAxis
        xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
        xAxis.labelFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 10, weight: .light)
        xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 192/255, blue: 56/255, alpha: 1)
        xAxis.axisLineColor = UIColor.lightGray
        xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true
        xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        xAxis.centerAxisLabelsEnabled = false
        xAxis.granularity = 1
        xAxis.labelRotationAngle = -90.0

        // MARK: leftAxis
        leftAxis.labelPosition = .outsideChart
        leftAxis.labelFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 10, weight: .light)
        leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        leftAxis.granularityEnabled = true
        leftAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 192/255, blue: 56/255, alpha: 1)

        // MARK: rightAxis
        rightAxis.enabled = false

        // MARK: legend
        legend.enabled = false

        // MARK: animation
        animate(xAxisDuration: 1.5)
    }


    func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

        var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

        for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
            let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry.init(x: Double(i), y: values[i])
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }

        let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
        lineChartDataSet.mode = .cubicBezier
        let lineChartData = LineChartData(dataSet: lineChartDataSet)
        data = lineChartData

        scaleXEnabled = true
        scaleYEnabled = false
        setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10.0)
        xAxis.setLabelCount(11, force: false)

        print("Create Chart Successfully!") //Successfully show in console.
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```